The Aurora RDS autoscaling feature is not functioning correctly
The Aurora RDS autoscaling feature is not functioning correctly. I have created an instance manually and I want it to scale up when the CPU usage exceeds 40% and add 1 or 2 instances as needed. However, in my tests, either the scaling did not happen even when the CPU usage increased, or when I activated scaling, it added 1 instance without any CPU usage. How can I properly use the RDS Aurora autoscaling feature?


"or when I activated scaling, it added 1 instance without any CPU usage" Can you describe this in more detail? Are you saying it added a second instance, but the addition didn't affect the CPU usage on the first instance?
